# Get ALL tables in the database of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a SQL statement to get ALL tables in the particular database - including `INFORMATIONAL_SCHEMA` and `sys`.

Something like `SQLTables( NULL, NULL, NULL );` does - all catalogs with all schemas with all tables.

All answers I see here are returning only user created tables or even the subsets of it.

Comment: Please post the query you tried.

Comment: Aside... INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a view, not a table. Are you looking for all views as well as tables?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the user tables, user views, and system views, then

```
select schema_name(schema_id) schema_name, name object_name, type, type_desc 
from sys.system_views
union all 
select schema_name(schema_id) schema_name, name object_name, type, type_desc 
from sys.tables 
union all 
select schema_name(schema_id) schema_name, name object_name, type, type_desc 
from sys.views
```

This excludes [system base tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables?view=sql-server-ver16), which are tables, but you can't SELECT from them unless you're connected to the [Dedicated Administrator Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver16).

If you want those too, add

```
select schema_name(schema_id) schema_name, name object_name, type, type_desc 
from sys.objects 
where type = 'S'
```

If you just need a count of the objects, then you can push the UNION ALL into a subquery like this:

```
select count(*) table_count
from (
    select schema_name(schema_id) schema_name, name object_name, type, type_desc 
    from sys.system_views
    union all 
    select schema_name(schema_id) schema_name, name object_name, type, type_desc 
    from sys.tables 
    union all 
    select schema_name(schema_id) schema_name, name object_name, type, type_desc 
    from sys.views
) d
```

Comment: I believe those system tables ARE part of SQLTables() call I mentioned. But let me check.

Comment: That's interesting `SQLTables()` gives 389, but this query returns more rows. Any idea on the discrepancy?

Comment: The system base tables are listed in sys.objects with type S if you need them too.

Comment: Profiler would tell you.  The ODBC driver is just running a query.

Comment: any idea on how to get a count of those? I'm looking for a way to easily see if I need to update that list.

Comment: in my program I call `SQLTables( NULL, NULL, NULL )` to get the table list. And then I am starting the thread to see if I need to add/remove the table. But if the number of tables is not changed - I don't want to go thru and just want to exit.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a system view for that also**, it's called [`sys.all_objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-all-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```sql
select
  o.name,
  s.name schema_name,
  o.type,
  o.type_desc
from sys.all_objects o
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
where o.type IN ('U', 'V', 'IT', 'S');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b66fe3581efc8cbd5b0f913049004c52)

You should generally avoid `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` it is for compatibility only.

Comment: WOW! This gives even more rows then both SQLTables() and the query from "David Brown" ;-) Now I don't know who to trust. BTW - I am testing on the SQL Server 2012 local copy...

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly. `U` is user tables, `S` is system tables, `IT` is certain internal tables and `V` are user and system views.

Comment: I understand. Problem is in my code I call SQLTables() ODBC API which should give all tables in all schemas for all catalogs. In my test DB I'm getting the number of tables as 386. When I tried to run the query provided by "David Brown" - I got the number of tables as 486. And when I run your query - the number of rows is even bigger - 537. So now my problem is - who to trust.

Comment: Adding the system base tables to David's query will bring the number of tables to 531, which is also not the same as yours.

Comment: It looks like adding system base table and removing sys.views portion gives the same result as yours. But I'm still confused as to why there is a discrepancy with the SQLTables() API..

Comment: This query and David's only give tables in the current database, plus system tables. So it's the equivalent of `SQLTables('DBname', NULL, NULL, NULL)`

Comment: I understand. I'm just curious why the difference then. The first part of David's query already gives 451 records I have made 35. So there is 100 tables difference. Just want to now where they are.

Comment: or maybe I should forget about SQLTables( and se this query instead?

Comment: Compare the results to find exact differences. Like I said: both his and mine will only give the current database and `master`

Comment: the first difference is `INFORMATION SCHAME.PRIVILEGES`. Any idea why it is not in the `SQLTables()` resuultset?